# Are any special security rights required to read performance data counters on Windows?

Tags: c++, security, winapi, performancecounter

I'm working on migrating a Windows application from always running as the `SYSTEM` account to running as a limited user account. One of the many things this application does is query [Windows Performance Counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373083(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to log the overall system memory and CPU usage. MSDN's [list of Privilege Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx) is vague, but `SE_PROF_SINGLE_PROCESS_NAME` or `SE_SYSTEM_PROFILE_NAME` strike me as being potentially required for this sort of operation. However, MSDN's documentation of functions such as [`PdhOpenQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372652(v=vs.85).aspx), [`PdhAddCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372204(v=vs.85).aspx), and [`PdhCollectQueryData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372563(v=vs.85).aspx) do not mention any required privileges.

Given this, does querying the Performance Data Counters require any privileges? Alternatively, what specifically do the `SE_PROF_SINGLE_PROCESS_NAME` or `SE_SYSTEM_PROFILE_NAME` privileges grant access to?

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: Partially because I don't trust my machine to work the same as every other machine out there (esp. Windows XP Embedded and other more exotic variations), particularly because my machine is a member of a corporate Windows domain. I'm hoping that I can learn from experiences of others that have gone before me. Perhaps there is a more detailed page in MSDN that I have missed.

Comment: You need to be a member of the Performance Monitor Users group to read performance counters, but I'm not sure which privileges this includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required privileges are mentioned in the description "About Performance Counters" [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Only the administrator of the computer or users in the Performance Logs User Group can log and view counter data. Users in the Administrator group can log and view counter data only if the tool they use to log and view counter data is started from a Command Prompt window that is opened with Run as administrator.... Users in the Performance Monitoring Users group can view counter data.
>
> Windows XP:  The Administrator or users in the Administrator group can log and view counter data without restriction.

Comment: For anyone else investigating this issue, this blog post may also be helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/09/08/746900.aspx.